# How to get src values of set of images inside div with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url, src, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I have a list of elements which contains an image & few more elements. I need to get the src of the image. HTML code is like this.

```
<div class="flex-card">
    <div class="flex-figure">
        <a href="">
            <figure class="image">
                <span class="fig-lable">Colombo</span>
                <img src="https://wenuka.com/media/visit-fl/banner-img.jpg" class="tile-media"/>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to get the src of the image with this code.

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("flex-figure");

for (var i = 0; i <= elem.length; i++) {
    var imgTag = elem[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    var srcLink = imgTag.src;
    console.log(srcLink);
}
```

It gives the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an off-by-one error, but why not use `querySelectorAll` instead, it'll be a lot cleaner:

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.flex-figure img');
imgs.forEach(img => console.log(img.src));
```

```html
<div class="flex-card">
    <div class="flex-figure">
        <a href="">
            <figure class="image">
                <span class="fig-lable">Colombo</span>
                <img src="https://wenuka.com/media/visit-fl/banner-img.jpg" class="tile-media"/>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

`querySelectorAll` is a lot more flexible than the `getElementsBy*` methods, and also returns a static NodeList which can be directly iterated over, unlike the other methods (which return live HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to deal with).

Comment: This is the best option! Much more flexible, you can use class, id or query selector.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (var i = 0; i <= elem.length; i++) {
```

To

```
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
```

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("flex-figure");

for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    var imgTag = elem[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    var srcLink = imgTag.src;
    console.log(srcLink);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-card">
    <div class="flex-figure">
        <a href="">
            <figure class="image">
                <span class="fig-lable">Colombo</span>
                <img src="https://wenuka.com/media/visit-fl/banner-img.jpg" class="tile-media"/>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Suresh.W, then problem should be some where else as you can see my answer run without any error....is it still the same error?

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")[0].src)
```

```html
<div class="flex-card">
    <div class="flex-figure">
        <a href="">
            <figure class="image">
                <span class="fig-lable">Colombo</span>
                <img src="https://wenuka.com/media/visit-fl/banner-img.jpg" class="tile-media"/>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```